# How to process each result -instead of line- of grep (oz) command (older then 2.25)

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

Starting from version 2.25, a ["bug" in grep](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=cce2fd5520bba35cf9b264de2f1b6131304f19d2) is fixed so null bytes, not newlines, are used to terminate output lines. 
This works as good as it's simple for capturing and processing multiline grep-matches (see example)

Unfortunately, I'm stuck with grep version 2.20 on production.
That means that for processing \n terminated logfiles, you can't differentiate the grep-match from each single line of output.

Therefore my question:

*What is the most efficient way to process each result -instead of line- of grep (oz) command when you're stuck with a version older then 2.25?*

(Note: this is a small example of a more complex script that needs to process more then 10k of big logfiles on request, therefore my quest for "the most efficient" solution)

A simple example:

test.log

```
flag test1
flag test2
flag test3
    test4
    test5
flag test6

test7

flag test8
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#regex explained: 
#(?s)enable multiline pattern search
#(flag) capturegroup with pattern indicating new entry
#[[:blank:]] followed by a space
#(.*?) capturegroup for the rest of the entry, non-greedy
#(?=(?:\r\n|[\r\n])(flag)|\z) positive lookahead: 
# - stop when the next newline begins with flag 
# - OR if last entry is a match: proceed 'till end of entry

regex_multiline="(?s)(flag)[[:blank:]](.*?)(?=(?:\r\n|[\r\n])(flag)|\z)"
logfile="./test.log"

test1(){
    #this works only with grep 2.25 or higher, 
    #which returns a NULL-byte delimiter after each capture
    echo start
    while IFS= read -r -d '' line ; do
        printf '<test>%s</test>\n' "$line"
    done < <(grep -Pzo $regex_multiline $logfile)
    echo end
}

test2(){
    #I need this to work for each match, instead of each line
    echo start
    while IFS= read -r line ; do
        printf '<test>%s</test>\n' "$line"
    done < <(grep -Pzo $regex_multiline $logfile)
    echo end
}
```

Test 1 results in, what I want:

```
start
<test>flag test1</test>
<test>flag test2</test>
<test>flag test3
        test4
        test5</test>
<test>flag test6

test7
 </test>
<test>flag test8</test>
end
```

Test 2 results in

```
start
<test>flag test1</test>
<test>flag test2</test>
<test>flag test3</test>
<test>       test4</test>
<test>       test5</test>
<test>flag test6</test>
<test></test>
<test>test7</test>
<test> </test>
<test>flag test8</test>
end
```

Comment: Test 2 fails, because you have removed the null de-limiter `-d ''` in `read`,  but `grep` keeps producing output, `NULL` delimited

Comment: No, Test 2 fails with `-d ''`, because grep pre 2.25 does *not* produce null-output, but \n instead. (as referenced in the link in my OP). If you'd try Test1 with grep <2.25, you'l ljust get `start\nend`

Comment: Are you allowed to use other tools or it has to be done with grep?

Comment: Yes sure! but when I start using `echo "$this" | cut -d "that"` the performance goes down the drain. I tried turning the situation around with using `tr '\n '\0' | grep -Pzo etc.` but I didn't manage to get it to work past `while IFS= read -r -d '\n' line ; do`

Comment: Would something like this work? `tr '\n' '-' <file |sed 's/^flag/<test>\0/g; s/-flag/<\/test>\n<test>\0/g; s/<test>-/<test>/g; $s/$/<\/test>/' |tr '-' '\n'` Performance seems to be bad, but you give a try....

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou sorry for the delay, but I'm definitely going to test your solution as soon as I can. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It's a bit hack-isch, I guess, but it's consistent with grep version 2.20 and up. Though don't use it with grep 2.25 and up.
It's the combination of grep with parameters -zon:
- z (Treat  the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte)
- o (Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty)  parts  of a matching line)
- n (Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.)

This combination will output a "1:" at the start of each new match. Always.
(not sure if it's a bug in grep, or by design, but it does make sense with the options -z and -o)

```
1:flag test1
1:flag test2
1:flag test3
    test4
    test5
1:flag test6

test7

1:flag test8
```

So, knowing this, this will result in the following find-and-replace function that will replace each line starting with 1: with a null-byte character. Note that a null-byte character is expected at the end of each line, so we'll have to add one manually for the last line!

This can be done with:

sed -e 's/^1:/\x0/g' | sed -e '$a\x0' 
or
awk '{gsub(/^1:/,"\x0");}1' | sed -e '$a\x0'

(I think sed is more efficient/faster for this kind of operation, but don't pin me down on this.)

```
test2(){
    #This finally works!
    echo start
    while IFS= read -r -d '' line ; do
        printf '<test>%s</test>\n' "$line"
    done < <(grep -Pzon $regex_multiline $logfile | sed -e 's/^1:/\x0/g' | sed -e '$a\\x0' )
    echo end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd best off using `perl` instead of `grep` here.  You can use your regex almost unmodified<sup>1</sup>, just have it substitute `\1\x00`<sup>2</sup>:

```
regex_multiline="(?s)(flag[[:blank:]].*?)(?=(?:\r\n|[\r\n])flag|\z)"
perl -0777 -pe "s/$regex_multiline/\1\x00/g" < "$logfile"
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Your regex was a little weird, with capturegroups that didn't do anything in the context of your grep command (like `(flag)`).  I just put the whole part you want to match into one group so that it would correspond to `\1` in the replacement part.  Adjust if needed/I'm missing something.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>Using `\1\0` (for "match group one", "null byte") actually works too but that seems kind of confusing.</sup>

Comment: True that the regex capturegroups don't have any use in grep, but in the original script the same regex is re-used in a `while read etc. ~= "$regex_multiline"` and `<tag>${BASH_REMATCH[1]}</tag> etc...`

Comment: sorry for the delay, but I'm definitely going to test your solution as soon as I can. I'll let you know.